# How to Retrieve a URL from the DOM using Dart

Tags: javascript, html, dart

When are they going to write that javascript to Dart transpiler? lol

I need to retrieve a URL from a web page. This is a javascript example.

```
url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href')
```

How do I do this in Dart? Update, fixed the name mismatch, didn't fix the problem.

I tried:

```
UrlInputElement page;
page = querySelector('.pagination .next a');
```

I'm not sure to the variable assignment. Url didn't work.

The pertinent html:

```
 <nav class="pagination">
   <span class="page current">1</span>
   <span class="page">
   <a rel="next" href="/artists?page=2">2</a></span>
   <span class="page">
   <a href="/artists?page=3">3</a></span>
   <span class="page">
   <a href="/artists?page=4">4</a></span>
   <span class="page">
   <a href="/artists?page=5">5</a></span>
   <span class="page gap">&hellip;</span>
   <span class="next">
   <a rel="next" href="/artists?page=2">Next &rsaquo;</a></span>
   <span class="last">
   <a href="/artists?page=64">Last &raquo;</a></span>
</nav>
```

I'm using Kaminari and am trying to add infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Could this work? I haven't tested it, because I don't have your html file.

`var page = querySelector('.pagination .next a').attributes['href'];`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was a stupid spelling error. I'll leave this up in case someone has the same question. This works:

```
AnchorElement page;
page = querySelector('.pagination .next a');
print(page.href)
=> http://jazzcat.loc/artists?page=2
```